# Calculating alpha level for Bonferroni

Tags: anova, bonferroni, two-way

I have 4 null hypotheses. I want to conduct 4 two-way mixed ANOVAs (one between-subjects factor and one within-subjects factor) for each of my 4 dependent variables. I will use the same between-subjects variable and within-subjects variable for each of the 4 different dependent variables  When I do the post-hoc repeated measured t-tests, for the Bonferroni correction, should I divide the α value (0.05) by 4 or by 2?

Thank you!

Comment: In general it's the number of $p$-values being compared, which you haven't exactly said.  If you're comparing 4 $p$-values, 1 from the ANOVA hypothesis of each model, then divide by 4.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to not use [Holm's procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method).